# Closed connection when connecting MSSQL on Rails through ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, activerecord

I wrote database.yml

```
  default: &default
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: 
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: 
  password:
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: 
  encoding: unicode

production:
  <<: *default
  database:
```

Rails tells me TinyTds::Error: closed connection.

Although, on rails c works.

```
irb(main):006:0> client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => '', :password => "", :host => "")
=> #<TinyTds::Client:0x00000006975a80 @message_handler=nil, @query_options={:as=>:hash, :symbolize_keys=>false, :cache_r
ows=>true, :timezone=>:local, :empty_sets=>true}>
irb(main):007:0> client.dead?
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
```

PS:mac terminal

Comment: I'm using MSSQL, not mysql.